# variable is filled, but still next command says it is empty

Tags: powershell, dpm

Code

```
$PGroup = Invoke-Command -ComputerName "xx.example.net" -ScriptBlock {Get-DPMProtectionGroup -DPMServerName "xx.example.net" | ft name -HideTableHeaders}
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName "xx.example.net" -ScriptBlock {Get-DPMJob -ProtectionGroup $PGroup -Status Failed}
```

Error :-

> Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ProtectionGroup'. The argument
> is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and
> then try the command again.
> + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-DPMJob], ParameterBindingValidationException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.Internal.EnterpriseStorage.Dls.UI.Cmdlet.GetDpmJobCmdlet

Comment: Remove `| ft name -HideTableHeaders` and in the line below do `-ProtectionGroup ($using:PGroup).Name`. The `Format-*` cmdlets are for **display on screen purposes only**. You should not use them if you want to process the variable any further

Comment: Theo's point is also worth heeding (elaborated on in the 2nd linked duplicate), but the primary problem is that you need the `$using:` scope in order to reference the value of a _local_ variable in  _remote_ call - see the 1st linked duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Format-table converts your object for display in the terminal, but you don't want that if you're using it downstream for another purpose.

Comment: While that is also a good point, note that the primary problem, as implied by the error message, is the attempt to access a _local_ variable in a _remote_ script block withou the `$using:` scope.